# Вызов функции хотя бы с одним аргументом, какой тип?

Tags: javascript, typescript

Есть функция

```
type Time = {
  days?: number
  hours?: number
  minutes?: number
  seconds?: number
}

const timeToMilliseconds = ({ days, hours, minutes, seconds }: Time) => {
  if (days) return days * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;
  if (hours) return hours * 60 * 60 * 1000;
  if (minutes) return minutes * 60 * 1000;
  if (seconds) return seconds * 1000;
};
```

Проблема в том, что мне постоянно приходится делать проверку на `undefined` когда я ее использую, это связано с тем что функция может вернуть `undefined` вместо числа, это произойдет в том случае если она будет вызвана без аргументов.

Вопрос в том как создать тип который будет указывать на то что в функция должна быть вызвана хотя бы с одним аргументом, для того что бы исключить возврат `undefined` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- [песочница](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEBBJBvAUEnT4HtgoAXJAbQBMQBPKAGiQAt8BXAJ3qTAEtgXjoDKBALAKUALpIAvOQCMDAEwMAzAwAsE7LmLUYyACrdIMjNty4qtAPwAuJHzAAjCG3MWmrDnYctnr9wsePgEoH0cXNw9cYVFxcL9I9wBfTHdQSFgEQzkzaJxREiRiYwgDfABZbgAbau5YwnFTAAp0JCtOZnZOYP5BJAaxKCRk%20yNIAEoZAD48-ItuADMkZo6ptghidmB2mmGAKiRFdSRDgDYABlOkS%20u5C4eAbkD8pZWujnXN7c9u69vzldDvcni9om9mr1Ql8tmwdlDoP8gUgQRdnvMFstmoNxDCfjiDiiHmiwR4NrCdhdSal5gB6WkAAWIUAAtBAAB76eDENlsNj4NhIUklSDlKq1eoiRpQVrJCb0pCAfhBANwggD4QQCiIKqkCykIBeEEArCCAIRAkKrABIggA4QQCMIIAuEHNwtKYpqdQJrV2tBG8tpSHwAGt7aLKk7JXEZW0PsM5Qrff6yoGJS62giI57vX75iLY%20LnVKhq6CR6o2n8vSmayOVyea5%20VF8hnHfGc%20JXR0GOGGEmhI3kwqDcazVbbSk0hYMtA4IgkAZFHNooVSHW49mQy02i3fhx27w%20px86NJ6UptJZlgMbgIWskOSfh1rsckffgcT0aekBDw3i4evCQCbsjUc-TwhJMP3hLdQgfIlQRfV8sQJECBi7O4n1JCwIGqYRikYfkAHcHAgXCDD0CAAFE%20QFZoAHI1zbLgwMREAxAQ5d6gcfBSGEYgKImalSRLZk2U5ERKzImtogXLNg2lWUUxVDUtR1XsTQtG07XTB1F0k3NVz2AsvWjNSAwkhMv101MY3rJcpMTOjuz0osxPUoyuzzRDIzs3jGX48shN5atzI04zqK8HobM7Zc3L1I0lIHVTcFSVI0lHLIJwAIRnPBCCKSg9lbYLNxCfoCSkWQyAUI5VA0LR0nAMdsknXIT1rIj90gAB9adZG02h7AiVwRiQAAfDAvx6xI%20uSQbhqTUb-EFCahraAkZsiEZSTnYpHKDfNZGaDMxlKdrD2PFCzyxKi9go18dgzeCMwAOhvQ470BCD-xOnAIQo8NLt4DbJkvb5P3u8MIJ-N7oM%20pMfuug8AYpP6IDupNXuQiGzoJaGEdu0o7vzR8oJfNCMOILD8Fw4B8MnIjSOrSigu6fLtyQBiKCY6VX2GYA2IQzjuPmGli08stBO5XyBX8pyQ2kwttUnABlJBAEEQVVVUtQBJEEABhAotV6KbX1CWtucrrbLMgzM0NqWw2C0z9NrTaG0t2iCpN22HMMi2rLZoYbfsjw%20OFisxdEjxxI9rS3U6PKne3ML2YixT%20xUodqsycdDGnRrogVXgBDYRY6tDh32czkPmoAEkLyzvc696Vj24aOmW8aJibtgAIxXbSnsK3ulbj1W-b%20ZO8gbvo9CPu5QH2vh4gUelt8Wb%204XyJB7itbMvne2q-EewK63zSmh2%20uACUpTYCgAB4GOoBhr%20mI70vmT6Okxm64Z%20e7HqOE4Xt-yCSTRisL6wVX6wyvEDHGIM-5g1Ri%20SGNlQH-XATDSASMbIowJoBdGXZEEQGxqgvG-9V7RCJsgEmOE8IEWpiJOmOUvyM3AizL2TQWJc3YpsLiPE6RCwEoHKs4szYWQPqGCKvpZYGAVsrVWmttaWl1tafWgiApGwjj7A2Rdw4g1Eb7CwldhGumRto9R29QzMJdjo3A-teE%20X4cHXR%209Ap0Joh2MxpkJFKxVurLWfY5GJwUUOVIQA)
- [`// @ts-expect-error`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-9.html#-ts-expect-error-comments)
- [Function Overloads](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/do-s-and-don-ts.html#function-overloads)

### namespace A

> для того что бы исключить возврат undefined

```
namespace A {
    const [days, hours, minutes, seconds] = [1, 2, 3, 4]
    type Time = {
        days?: number
        hours?: number
        minutes?: number
        seconds?: number
    }

    namespace T1 {
        const timeToMilliseconds = ({ days, hours, minutes, seconds }: Time) => {
            if (days) return days * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;
            if (hours) return hours * 60 * 60 * 1000;
            if (minutes) return minutes * 60 * 1000;
            if (seconds) return seconds * 1000;
            return 0
        }
        //@ts-expect-error 
        timeToMilliseconds({})// плохо - нет ошибки
        timeToMilliseconds({ days })// ok
        timeToMilliseconds({ hours })// ok
        timeToMilliseconds({ minutes })// ok
        timeToMilliseconds({ seconds })// ok
        //@ts-expect-error
        timeToMilliseconds({ days, hours, minutes, seconds })// нет ошибки
    }

    namespace T2 {
        const timeToMilliseconds = ({ days, hours, minutes, seconds }: Time) => {
            if (days) return days * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;
            if (hours) return hours * 60 * 60 * 1000;
            if (minutes) return minutes * 60 * 1000;
            if (seconds) return seconds * 1000;
            else throw new TypeError('days, hours, minutes and seconds is not set')
        }
        //@ts-expect-error
        timeToMilliseconds({})// плохо - нет ошибки
        timeToMilliseconds({ days })// ok
        timeToMilliseconds({ hours })// ok
        timeToMilliseconds({ minutes })// ok
        timeToMilliseconds({ seconds })// ok
        //@ts-expect-error
        timeToMilliseconds({ days, hours, minutes, seconds })// нет ошибки
    }
}
```

### namespace B

> функция должна быть вызвана хотя бы с одним аргументом

```
namespace B {
    const [days, hours, minutes, seconds] = [1, 2, 3, 4]

    namespace T1 {
        type Time_2 = { days: number } | { hours: number } | { minutes: number } | { seconds: number }
        const timeToMilliseconds = (time: Time_2) => {
            if ('days' in time) return time.days * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;
            if ('hours' in time) return time.hours * 60 * 60 * 1000;
            if ('minutes' in time) return time.minutes * 60 * 1000;
            if ('seconds' in time) return time.seconds * 1000;
            else throw new TypeError('days, hours, minutes and seconds is not set')
        }
        //@ts-expect-error
        timeToMilliseconds({})// ok - TS сообщает об ошибке
        timeToMilliseconds({ days })// ok
        timeToMilliseconds({ hours })// ok
        timeToMilliseconds({ minutes })// ok
        timeToMilliseconds({ seconds })// ok
        //@ts-expect-error
        timeToMilliseconds({ days, hours, minutes, seconds })// нет ошибки
    }

    namespace T2 {
        // interface $timeToMilliseconds {
        type $timeToMilliseconds = {
            (time: { days: number }): number;
            (time: { hours: number }): number;
            (time: { minutes: number }): number;
            (time: { seconds: number }): number;
        }
        const timeToMilliseconds: $timeToMilliseconds = (time: Record<any, any>) => {
            if ('days' in time) return time.days * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;
            if ('hours' in time) return time.hours * 60 * 60 * 1000;
            if ('minutes' in time) return time.minutes * 60 * 1000;
            if ('seconds' in time) return time.seconds * 1000;
            else throw new TypeError('days, hours, minutes and seconds is not set')
        }
        //@ts-expect-error
        timeToMilliseconds({})// ok - TS сообщает об ошибке
        timeToMilliseconds({ days })// ok
        timeToMilliseconds({ hours })// ok
        timeToMilliseconds({ minutes })// ok
        timeToMilliseconds({ seconds })// ok
        //@ts-expect-error
        timeToMilliseconds({ days, hours, minutes, seconds })// TS сообщает об ошибке
    }
}
```